# Gorilla Web Toolkit Sessions Memcache Implementation

Tags: session, go, memcached, gorilla

Am trying to implement Gorilla Web Toolkit sessions against a memcached cluster.  The Gorilla site lists this as the memcache support: https://github.com/hnakamur/gaesessions but it requires the "appengine" package.

**Does anyone know of a simple memcache session storage backend in pure Go that doesn't require the appengine package?**

Would be easy to write (using something like https://github.com/bradfitz/gomemcache to do the actual memcache work) but didn't want to bother if there's one out there that I somehow missed in my googling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Couldn't find anything, so I went ahead and put this together:

https://github.com/bradleypeabody/gorilla-sessions-memcache